# Can't retrieve HashMap inputs in another method

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, hashmap

I got a small problem that I can't figure out.

I have a superclass (SetupFunctions) which I have used in my HashMap -->

```
public HashMap<Integer, SetupFunctions> map =  new HashMap<Integer, SetupFunctions>();
```

And all the other classes extends that `SetupFunction`.
I need to do like 160 methods which retrives unique data and I need to store that data in one  place to check later (it's an automated test).
Thats why I have the type `SetupFuncition` in the HashMap.

So, I instantiate a class with a constructor and then add it in the hashmap:

```
MyClass m = new MyClass (car1, var2, var3, var4, var5);
map.put(getCenarioID(), m);
```

On the same method, I added some sysout just to see what's happening:

```
System.out.println(map.containsKey(1));
System.out.println(map.size());
```

As expected, it prints True and 1... But when I leave this method (end of the execution of the method) and goes back to the main method, that same sysout prints False and 0.

I want to know why my hashmap is empty or reseting... That not suppose to happend... Am I right?

Comment: Where is your `Map` variable located? Do the main method and the method which puts MyClass in the map really use the same variable? Can you produce a short code that shows the same behaviour, so you and we can find out what is happening?

Comment: it will be helpful if you post the code of maim and that other method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say what is really going on using the information provided. But it seems that you are probably using two different `HashMap`s named `Map`, one inside the method and another outside.

I think you have two (possibly more) variables named `Map` - one is a member of your class, while the other is an element of your driver class (i.e. the class where your main method is declared) or a variables inside the main method itself.

Comment: Oh, i though i edited the question but i found the solution.
I was debugin and i found that the method that was filling the HashMap was called by non static istance ( object i =new object() ) when the instance finish, it earesed the hashmap.. so i change the calling code and now it works like a charm. thks people!

Answer (score 1):

Is `Map` static or being dynamically accessed? That's the only way your main could properly access it. Make sure there are no duplicate variables `Map` that might be confusing the compiler.

If you could post the code here, that would be best.